# Is the wavelength of the light emitted from an LED at its turn-on voltage greater than or less than the peak wavelength of the LED?

Tags: voltage, led

Ok, so I know that the intensity of the light given by an LED is the minimum it can be at the turn-on voltage, however I don't know if the wavelength of the light emitted from the LED at the turn-on voltage will be below the peak wavelength (the wavelength at which the intensity of the light of the LED is at its maximum) or above it. My reasoning comes from the picture below:[image]

The picture shows that for a specific colour of LED, for any intensity instead of the peak intensity there can be two wavelengths associated with it. For instance, for the blue LED, there will two values for wavelength for when the intensity is 20%. So, my question is: Is the wavelength of the light emitted from an LED at its turn-on voltage greater than or less than the peak wavelength of the LED?

Comment: I don't think you're reading this right. This graph shows the _spread_ of the spectrum, meaning that the LED not only emits light at a single frequency, but in a range of frequencies centered around the middle, with a distribution as shown. It has nothing to do with the LED intensity.

Comment: @pipe The values in the y-axis, I believe, represent the normalised intensity (%). I have changed the picture to a more suitable one.

Comment: But you still talk about "two values", there are no such values. What the graph shows (the new and the previous) is still the _spread_. The LED emits light at _every_ wavelength shown under the curve. Simultaneously. It is not infinitely narrow-band.

Comment: @pipe So, say for the intensity of the purple LED at 40%, will there be two values for the wavelength of the light?

Comment: @pipe From what I hear, do you mean that for any intensity of the light there will be a similar spectrum for the wavelenght of the colour of LED emitted?

Comment: The chart is saying that there are two kinds of blue LED: one with its maximum output at 445 nm and the other with its maximum output at 465 nm.

Comment: No, when you turn on the puple LED to 40% of it's maximum power capability, it will emit a spectrum of power similar to what's shown on the graph, but scaled down to 40% of the maximum total power it's capable of. "Normalized intensity" means normalized to the peak in the spectrum that is currently being emitted.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yeah, I think I understand now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The wavelength distribution will look like the graph, pretty much regardless of current at a given temperature. LEDs are not purely monochromatic.

However, as the die heats (and it will tend to heat more at higher current) the center of the spectrum will shift toward the red for all LEDs (longer wavelength).

From this [OSRAM document](http://ledlight.osram-os.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/OSRAM-OS_LED-FUNDAMENTALS_Thermal-Characteristics-of-LEDs_v2_08-16-11_SCRIPT.pdf), you can see a typical change of about +70pm/K die temperature.

[image]

Comment: So, are you saying that for any specific current going through any specific colour of LED, the distribution of the wavelenght of the colour of the LED will be the same?

Comment: At the same **die temperature**, yes. The dominant wavelength (peak of the spectrum) will remain constant.

Comment: @SpehroPehfany Thanks a million! This makes my job sooooooooooooo much easier.

Comment: @SpenroPehfany Are you sure the dominant wavelenght is the peak of the spectrum? I thought they were different things.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that's not the technical definition when it refers to perception of color. It's technically "wavelength of the spectrum light that when combined in suitable proportions with the specified achromatic light yields a match with the light being considered" according to M-W.

Comment: Sorry, I was supposed to ask you this before, but would you have graph or explicit/simple source which shows that despite the current/voltage going through an LED the distribution of the colour of the LED will be the same? Thanks.

Comment: @user307397 such a graph would be out of spec for most datasheets, but is to be expected from the underlying physics -- I suggest a literature search.

Comment: So it's a slow function of temperature in the operating region.  The shape of the curve should be similar to the shape of the bandgap-temperature curve. If you pulse the LED really hard and have a time-resolved spectrometer you may be able to detect a shift over the length of a pulse. I may end up testing this in the next few months as part of an experiment.

Comment: It's probably **not** literally true. There is likely some small effect with current (perhaps in the opposite direction to heating). Maybe barometric pressure too. If you're looking at the last couple nm it might be significant, but the breadth of the spectrum and even unit-to-unit variations will likely swamp it. I've never seen a current dependency shown on an LED datasheet spectral density curve.

Answer (score 5):

First off, as pipe said, you are misinterpreting the graph. The graph merely shows the composition of the the output spectra when operating in a normal regime, not as a function of relative output power.

However, to answer this:

> Is the wavelength of the light emitted from an LED at its turn-on voltage greater than or less than the peak wavelength of the LED?

When an LED is "on" (operating in a normal regime, when the forward voltage is greater than the turn-on voltage and the forward current is less than the maximum), it emits a very narrow spectrum of light, centered around a wavelength that is determined by manufacture and temperature (and therefore, to a small extent, forward current).

By cooling an LED, the wavelength decreases. [This link](http://www.physics-astronomy.com/2014/06/watch-led-light-change-color-in-liquid.html) shows an LED going from orange to yellow when cooled in liquid nitrogen. Likewise, heating an LED increases the wavelength.

Consequently, when you apply a large current to an LED, it heats up and the wavelength increases.

When operating the LED at the turn-on voltage and a very small amount of current is passing through it, the LED is dissipating less energy than "normal" operating, so the temperature will be somewhat lower than usual. So it's possible that the wavelength is a *teeny, tiny* bit lower than typical, but realistically, it's exactly the same as when it's operating normally.

Answer (score 4):

LEDs are not monochromatic, meaning that their output emission is comprised of multiple different wavelengths of light. Your diagram is just showing the normalized amplitudes of the different wavelengths it produces.

As a comparison example, consider an incandescent lightbulb. White light as we see it is comprised of light of all visible wavelengths. A 3000K bulb looks orange because the most powerful emissions that we can see are those on the yellow-red side of the visible spectrum. Note how most power is converted into infrared energy, just radiating heat. Very large range of wavelengths.

[image]

On the other hand, a laser diode can be classified as monochromatic. Notice how narrow the range of emitted light is (0.5-1 nm) in comparison to the incandescent bulb. It's emission contains a much smaller range of wavelengths.

[image]

Addition:

In the middle of the bulb and laser emission bandwidth are LEDs - a small enough wavelength range (about one hundred nm) for them to be considered a specific color but not small enough to be considered monochromatic. Your diagram appears to show the spectra of multiple different LED diodes, here is a diagram showing the spectra of three different LEDs - "common blue LED, a yellow-green LED and a high brightness red LED from the bottom of a Microsoft optical mouse" [Image, Description Source and more info](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Red-YellowGreen-Blue_LED_spectra.png)

[image]

Comment: You don't actually include a graph for a LED, but it's closer to the laser one than the incandescent one :)

Comment: I didn't include for LEDs because the original question had a good one, but I'll find one specific to LEDs and edit it in when I get back to my computer.

Comment: LED Graphs added